# What settings are needed for Zurmo CRM to work on 1and1 hosts

Tags: email, smtp, crm, 1and1

[Zurmo CRM](http://zurmo.org) a free open source CRM system supports (as of Jan 2017) only SMTP outgoing mail.

on [YOUR_CRM_DOMAIN/app/index.php/emailMessages/default/configurationEditOutbound](http://yourcrmdomain.com/app/index.php/emailMessages/default/configurationEditOutbound) I set the following attributes. The values in the parenthesis are taken from [1and1.com help page "E-mail Software Setup Credentials"](https://help.1and1.com/e-mail-and-office-c37589/1and1-mail-basic-c37590/using-the-product-c85088/e-mail-software-setup-credentials-a616889.html)

```
Host *    (imap.1and1.com)
Port *    (587)
Username  (e.g. user.email@user.domain.com)
Password  (e.g. mypassword)
Extra Mail Settings (tls)
Send a test email to (e.g. random.user@gmail.com)
```

When attempting to send the test outgoing mail, I get the error message

```
Message failed to send
Error Code: 0
Error Message: Connection could not be established with host smtp.1and1.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

What should be the correct values to make Zurmo CRM email work on 1and1.com shared hosts?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me.

1. The field "Extra Mail Settings" receives **ssl** or **tls** - for this solution leave this field **empty**
2. Set the port to **25**
3. Leave all other fields as shown in the question

Once I set the above and emailed the test mail I got the response "Message successfully sent"